# Searching for string in sqlite database

Tags: python, database, search, sqlite

I am currently making a login system for a project I am doing. I want to have Username as a unique identifier and I want to query the table to make sure it isn't already in use. When I print `IdExists` it returns 'none' even when the username is already in use. Any way for me to query the database and then get a true/false or something that tells me if the username exists? Thank you.

```
def NameInUse(Username):
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID =(?)',('%'+Username+'%',))
IdExists=cursor.fetchone()
if IdExists==True:
    LoginScrn.addLabel('Error','Username already in use')
    return True
else
    return False
```

Comment: Remove the `%`.

Comment: Why not just index the column based on username? Faster lookups and prevents duplication?
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/

Comment: By using %username% check you are preventing anyone using a username which is part of existing username. Ie if I have registered user "Tomas123" you can't anymore register user "Tom". Also you should compare uppercased both usernames to avoid registering "tom", "ToM" etc if "Tom" already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove each `'%'` and the `()`s from the parameter specification. Instead of `'%'`, provide a tuple:

```
def NameInUse(Username):
   data = list(sqlite3.connect('tablename.db').cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = ?', (username,)))
   return bool(data)
```

Comment: @VictoriaWorthington glad to help!